# How to extrude a 2cm base for an uneven surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude, 3d-printing

I am trying to extrude a 2 or 3 cm solid baseplate for this landscape.
It has to be the same formation as the cutout, as I'm going to 3D print it.

What is the easiest way to do so? Thank you!

.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Do you mean to add thickness with flat base, so it doesn't wobble?

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

- Select the boundary of your object.
- Extrude it 2cm.
- Make an N-gon face from the resulting edges, or grid fill, if that works better.